# Disk speed and partitioning

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, virtual-machine

I am using VMWare for creating multiple virtual machines running games, each virtual machine has its own game installation (and i don't want to use common install)

BEFORE:
Everytime the game on each virtual machine were loading (accessing the game files, i believe) the disk usage goes to 100% and slows everything down.

NOW:
As a solution i'm running 2 virtual machines on each of my 3 harddisks and the loading time is much faster, and all disks usage go to 100%

QUESTION: Does partitioning these disks with one partition for each virtual machine will make it faster aswell? Or do i need to buy more disks?

PS:
I also considered buying a 240GB SSD and run 5 virtual machines there (maybe without the need of partitioning). But prefer to avoid spending money...
I currently have 3 SATA II disks

What do you think?
Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

more hard drives and or SSD make it faster.  An SSD is usually 5x or more faster based only on mb/s.  Latency on a SSD is orders of magnitude faster.
Partitioning by itself does nothing for speed if utilization is 100%.

On a traditional hard drive with spinning platters, the outside tracks hold more data, and there for are faster than inner tracks.  However, the difference is not enough to be of help to you.  Some people shrink the last partition on the hard drive to avoid the slowest part of the disk.  If 2 games max out your IO then even the best optimization of partitions will not get you 3.

However, an SSD has no platters or spinning so the storage is the same everywhere, and thus the issue can be avoided all together.